# Whitespace within environment variable value

Tags: cmd, environment-variables, whitespace

Is it possible to assign a value like `C:\Program Files` to the `PATH` environment variable? Wouldn't the whitespace cause an error?
Can I use something like that:

```
set ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-ant
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%
```

Comment: Did you try that? Did that not answer your question?

Comment: Yes and I gained no result. I mean no values were appended to PATH variable. Moreover I tried to include paths in double quotes. That didn't help too.

Comment: It's normal that these commands produce no output.

Comment: I checked both ways `MyComputer->Properties->Advanced->EnvironmentVariables` and `echo %PATH%` from command shell. They aren't there.

Comment: Those commands are also not persistent (only in the current shell/cmd.exe)

Comment: I understand. So whitespace presence (inside path value) really doesn't matter. But if they're not persistent howcome Ant uses them? Should I define them each time I make a build?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on either `EV (environment variables)` permanent setup and use of a whitespace in the `EV` value. The answer is here: https://superuser.com/questions/289179/set-environment-variables-from-command-line-and-make-them-stick-globally.